# On a pandiagonal Latin square, what is a broken diagonal?

Tags: combinatorics, latin-square

After reading ["No pandiagonal latin squares with order divisible by 3?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/173127/11619) I didn't understand what a "broken diagonal" is.

Thanks

Comment: I quoted the question in mine, it is not a duplicate, but I do think I now understand what a broken diagonal is.  I think it is a diagonal containing less entries or cells than the order of the Latin square.

Comment: Sorry, Darren. I'm just so used to the hypertext point of view of "quoting" = "giving a link". I took the liberty of adding that link to your post. Click the edit -button to see how it is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broken diagonals are collections of $n$ cells - one on each row and column. They are parallel to one of the main diagonals but they wrap around when the diagonal reaches a border of the square. So either a set of cells in positions $(i,i+k)$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$,
and a fixed $k$, or in positions $(i,i-k)$. The arithmetic on the column indices is done modulo $n$. Changing the value of $k$ gives another broken diagonal.

For example in the following latin square the red cells form one broken diagonal and
the green cells another one. The brown number is in their intersection.
$$
\pmatrix{
0&\color{Red}2&4&6&\color{Green}1&3&5\cr
1&3&\color{Red}5&\color{Green}0&2&4&6\cr
2&4&\color{Green}6&\color{Red}1&3&5&0\cr
3&\color{Green}5&0&2&\color{Red}4&6&1\cr
\color{Green}4&6&1&3&5&\color{Red}0&2\cr
5&0&2&4&6&1&\color{Brown}3\cr
\color{Red}6&1&3&5&0&\color{Green}2&4\cr
}
$$

Comment: Thank you for that, I'm new to stack exchange, and to the mathematical language of Latin squares.  I guess I need to find a forum. Any recommendations?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help you in looking for a better forum. Douglas Stones is the top guy on Latin squares here, but he hasn't been around lately. IIRC he started on another research theme after getting his PhD.Just look at [the earlier questions on latin squares}(http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin-square). You will find that many people can answer basic questions here. Here's to hoping that you find Math.SE of use.

Answer (score 2):

My illustration for broken diagonals

[image]

Please see this thread
https://boinc.progger.info/odlk/forum_thread.php?id=178

Comment: Welcome on the MathSE! I inserted your image link into your post, but link-only answers are not allowed here. It means that if you provide a link in your answer, you need to copy-paste the most important part of the remote content into your post. It is because remote links often go down, making your answer incomprehensible. Your answer need to be comprehensible even without opening the remote link.